# Creating a magnifying-glass effect in three.js WebGL

Tags: three.js

I'm working with an orthographic view in three.js/WebGL renderer, and I want a magnifying glass that tracks with the user mouse. I'm looking for the best way of doing this that's efficient.

When working with html5 canvas raw commands, this was easy: I simply defined a circular clip region, zoomed my coordinates, and re-drew the whole scene. With 3d objects, it's less obvious how do to it.

The method I've found so far is to do the following:

- Define a second camera that looks into the zoomed region. Set the orthographic clip coordinates to be small so that it doesn't need to do much work
- Create a THREE.WebGLRenderTarget
- Tell the renderer and all my line textures that the resolution is about to change
- Render the scene into the RenderTarget
- Add a CircleGeometry as a MeshObject at the spot at the mouse position (in world coordinate but above the rest of the scene, close to the camera). Call this the lens.
- Give the lens the WebGLRenderTarget as a texture.
- Go back to my default camera, reset all my resolution parameters, and redraw the scene with the 'lens' object added.

This works (see image below) but I'm worried about parts of it:

- I have to render twice per frame
- Lines don't draw well, because the resolution problems. I have to keep track of all materials that need to know screen resolution and update all of them twice per screen render.

Related problems:

- I want to overlay some plot axes on top of this, and possibly gridlines.  These would change as the view pans.  I'm not sure if I should make these 3d objects, or do it in a 2d canvas context I lay overtop.
- I want to overlay some plot lines, and have them show up sensibly in the zoomed view. "Sensible" here is hard to figure out: I don't want them too fat in the zoomed view, but I also don't want to scale them up as much as the image detail (which is being rendered as a texture onto Plane objects behind).

This is a long post, but I'm still new to three.js and looking for good ideas.

[image: example]

Comment: I don't have an answer for this but I'm very interested to see it happen.

Comment: you can do it as post effect in fragment shader, but it is no really magifying, only stretch picture  https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/VNMbOV

Comment: @stranger-in-th-q That's a cool demo. You're right, it doesn't really fulfill the remit, since the detail isn't increased.  I wonder if you could somehow do that, but over-render the whole scene? (i.e. turn resolution up, but scale the HTML element down...?)

Comment: Have you seen this? https://amitdiamant.github.io/magnify-3d/